# Request.URL always returns http

Tags: web, https, load-balancing

My problem has been asked here: [Request.URL always returns http even though SSL is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599070/request-url-always-returns-http-even-though-ssl-is-enabled) but I do not see any workable solution in my situation.
So my website is hosted on a server which is behind a loadbalancer which causes all requests to contain the urls having http protocol even though the original request from clients contain https. Now this post: http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2013/12/identifying-https-or-ssl-connection-in.html suggests that we can check for a custom header added by the loadbalancer and get the original protocol. But my problem is that I can't ask all of my clients to make sure that they are adding a custom header in their loadbalancer and provide me with the name of that custom header. Is there a way to fix this without getting any additional details from the loadbalancer?

Comment: No. If the load balancer doesn't forward the information, you simply won't have it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46683440/476

Comment: okay, if no other way around it, will ask for the detail. Thanks